# In App Purchase showing multiple times Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a TableViewController, in viewDidLoad , I'm requesting for all the products available and then reloading the tableview with number  of cells = number of products.
What is happening is when i click on buy Button and cancel it, It prints "Buy Cancelled" only once.
But When I go to some other viewcontroller and come back to this tablevc again (as I'm opening this tableVC again ViewDidLoad loads again) cells are loaded correctly. But then when I try to buy and click on cancel again. it prints "Buy Cancelled" Twice. 
If I go to other view and open this vc again. Then it prints Three times.... this goes on.
This is my viewDidLoad

```
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        var productIDs:NSSet = NSSet(objects: productOne, productTwo, productThree, productFour, productFive)
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
    }else{
        println("can't make purchases");
    }
```

and delegate Method

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction


        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased:
            println("Purchase Successful")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("Buy Cancelled")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be tough to answer without more details and relevant code.